# Can a rhombus of relationship have a primary key in ERD?

Tags: sql, erd

I got some troubles to understand the ERD. Can a rhombus of relationship have a primary key?

For example, is this legal?
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you are going to have to do a better job of explaining what the issue is. What, specifically, do you not understand about this ERD?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Chen's ERD notation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1499402.1499421),  attributes defined a mapping between entity sets and value sets.  So by definition, a relationship should not have attributes.

It appears that you have a many-to-many relation between lecturers and the class.  Each of this relationship may have different attributes, e.g. semester,  class-room, etc...  In this case you would use an **associative entity**, as explained in [this practical introduction to Chen's notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/):

[image: Diamond in an enclosing rectangle]

The associative entity is used exactly as a relationship would be (this is why it contains a diamond). But it is at the same time an entity that can have attributes.  And they could also have their own keys.

But in your case, `semester code` does not uniquely identify an entity, since many other `Teach`  would share the same semester code.  `Semester code` only uniquely identifies an entity in combination with the key of the `Lecturer` and `Class`.  It is therefore a partial key:   the underlining should be dashed instead of continuous.