# How can I implement IF condition in ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I have the following ER diagrams:

- [customer starts a transaction with account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPJgB.png)
  [image]
- [Bank updates watch_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXXir.png)

[image]

I'm new to ER diagram and I want to add an alert system in banking process. `Customer` entity can start a transaction with his/her bank account in `transact_with` relationship. In the relationship, there are attributes such as `counterpart_name` and `counterpart_country`. If counterpart's name in remittance is the same as the name from `watch_list` the bank is keeping, the DB creates a new row in the table named `Alert`. And I wonder how can I establish that `Alert` entity and relationships between other entities.

Since `counterpart_name` is a attribute from a relationship, if I want to relate that attribute with `watch_list` entity, it seems like it becomes ternary relationship but I don't want `watch_list` to be related with `customer` and `account` entity in normal transaction process. Any suggestions on this, please?

Answer (score 2):

ERD won't help you because it doesn't capture rules.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Of course, if you want to create an ALERT table, then ERD is fine.

The "if" part which fires a trigger (or whatever) could be modeled by a UML sequence diagram (for example).

Put another way, the ALERT table is data, the "if" is control and they are served by different diagram types.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can and should relate the `ALERT` entity with the entity `WATCH_LIST` and `TRANSACT_WITH`:

- If these relationships would not exist, you would know to which watch list element the transaction is related, and use the score mentioned on the watchlist.  Moreover, what's the benefit of having alerts, if not knowing which transaction must be inspected/monitored?
- The fact that the `ALERT` is not systematic but conditional, can be documented with an optional relationship.
- The matching of the transaction with the watchlist is based on some criteria, but the relationship with the alert would be based on the id.

The ER diagrams show the structure of the entities and the relationships.  They do not describe the processes or the behaviors.  Typically, with an ERD, you'd use some DFD to explain what data is consumed by the monitoring process that would generate the ALERT records.  And the `IF` would be documented in the flowchart or pseudocode that documents this process.  On the other side, nothing prevents you from informally documenting this informally in a comment within your ERD.

Unrelated remarks:

- As you have lots of attributes on the relation `TRANSACT_WITH`,  and since [a relation is not supposed to have attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640405/3723423), I understand that it is in reality an associative entity.
- The matching of the watchlist solely on the base of the name (without even considering the country) might lead to a high number of false positives.
- UML would allow to constraint the ER-relationship (UML-association) with ER-entity (UML-Class) `ALERT`, and express the conditionality in a very precise manner.